# Cordova: write file into cdvfile java

Tags: java, cordova, plugins, filesystems

I created a plugin Cordova for Android (Java) which write into a file in the sdcard, and it works.

Now, I wanted to write this file into the temporary space "cdvfile://localhost/temporary" of the plugin Cordova FileSystem.

How can I do?

Thanks